# Combinatorial proof of nth power identity

Tags: combinatorics

Prove $1+{n \choose 1}2+{n \choose 2}4+...+{n \choose n-1}2^{n-1}+{n \choose n}2^n=3^n$ using combinatorial arguments.  I have no idea how to begin solving this, a nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: $\sum\binom{n}{k}2^k$ counts the pairs $(A,f)$ with $A\subseteq\{1,\cdots,n\}$ and $f:A\to\{1,2\}$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews right.

Answer (score 4):

Consider a set of strings with $n$ characters made up of $a$, $b$ or $c$. The total number of such string is the sum of the number of strings with $n$ $a$'s, the number of strings with $n-1$ $a$'s, $\cdots$, down to the number of strings with no $a$'s.

Answer (score 0):

Using red, green, and blue, how many ways can you paint a fence with $n$ pickets?

**Hint:** Count the number of ways to paint the fence if $k$ pickets are to be red or green. There are $\binom{n}{k}$ ways to select $k$ pickets to be painted red or green and for each of those choices, there are $2^k$ ways to paint those pickets. The remaining pickets are painted blue.